# Linux distribution for beginners

Tags: linux

I am a newbie willing to start learning hacking. So what I learnt was kali is not for beginner and absolutely not recommended for user like me which has very few idea about Unix systems.

So I prefer to use some user friendly Gnu/Linux such as mint and Ubuntu(32 bits)

So if I want to start from scratch, which Gnu/Linux would be recommend for me? (32 bit version only, on virtual box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a newbie willing to start learning hacking...

That two things don't go well together to be polite.

---

> ... what I learnt was Kali is not for beginners and absolutely not recommended for user like me...

This sounds awfuly scary, but probably correct in the core thing. There are a few things to learn before you start your *quest* as a *friendly* hacker.

---

> I prefer to use some user friendly Linux such as Mint and Ubuntu (32bit)

Start by learning the basic principles of any as you call it *friendly* Linux'es and you named them correctly, Ubuntu for desktop I think is being retired, the Unity desktop I mean, but Linux Mint, even the 32bit versions are still getting a lot of support from community.

---

Linux Mint 19.3 "Tricia" - Cinnamon (32-bit):

- link to [info web](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=273)
- link to [torrent download](https://torrents.linuxmint.com/torrents/linuxmint-19.3-cinnamon-32bit.iso.torrent)

---

If you are fast, you will likely learn the basic principles in a few months. Ethical hacking can and will have to wait until then.

---

One nice thing about Linux Mint is that you can literally use it for anything, start from the little command things, and you use it as your primary operating system like myself, which I've had too big troubles with Debian before for daily use.

---

Overall this question is, of course, opinion-based, and as such it should be closed, but let's show our newcomer how nice people we are and provide at least something.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with Ubuntu, is it tries to get you to install proprietary software. I don't know about mint.

I use Debian, the one that was went to be had to install. It is now easier to install than MS-Windows-7 (no licence key to type, and a few more bits installed by default. It is also easier to add more software, after the initial install.)

Also I use KDE plasma desktop (just a preference, I like to configure 1 or 2 things that can't be configured in most other modern desktops).

I use dolphin: it is like file-explorer. It has an integrated terminal. You can easily switch between the GUI (Graphical User Interface) and CLI (Command Line Interface), and it will keep track of current working directory which ever you use to change directory.

One tip is to have a separate partition for `/home`, it makes it easier when you change/upgrade the OS. You can keep the `/home` and wipe the rest. This way your initial decision does not matter too much, as you can change it. If using Virtual-box create too drives, so that you can easily create a new machine. However **do not** mount a drive to two machines at the same time.

Comment: Debian is a good stable, Free, system. The down-side it that some of the packages are a little dated (however security is up to date). If you need now stuff, then you install it your self (good excuse to learn how to compile code, and use `stow`), use docker (good excuse to learn docker), or use a different distro.